# TcpClient C# wait until new data are available

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcpclient

I'm trying to use tcpclient to retrieve data from a tcp server, sending a request and receiving a response, it works fine except for one thing.
When I try to use multiple times **networkstream.readasync** and then **networkstream.writeasync** the readasync function reads the previous response of the previous writeasync and not of the last one.To fix that I have to set a timeout before reading. Instead of setting a timeout is there any way to wait until the new data are available?

Pseudocode Example:

```
connectasync(host,port);
//reads a hello message from the server
networkstram.readasync();
//sending a request to the server
networkstram.writeasync();
//reads again the hello message from the previous read 
//not the response from the previously sended writeasync 
networkstram.readasync()
```

Pseudocode Solution:

```
connectasync(host,port);
//reads a hello message from the server
networkstram.readasync();
//sending a request to the server
networkstram.writeasync();
//wait for 1 second
wait(1000)
//reads correctly
networkstram.readasync()
```

If you have any better way to wait the newly available data instead of using a fixed timeout let me know.
Thank you.

**UPDATE**
**NOTE**:I even tried with the synchronous version of read and write still the same.
Am Just using async to no block the user interface.

```
    public async Task<string> sendQuery()
    {

        
        try
        {
            client.Connect(ConfigParameters.ip, ConfigParameters.port);
            if (client.Connected == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                var networkStream = client.GetStream();
                


                // Receive data from server
                //Receiving HELLO message from the server
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                var serverResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine("Server: " + serverResponse);
                Array.Clear(buffer,0,buffer.Lenght);
                Array.Resize(ref buffer, 1024);

                // Send data to server
                // send query to the server
                
                string data = QueryStore.queryStart+QueryStore.query1.getLRC() + QueryStore.queryEnd;
                buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                await networkStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                 Array.Clear(buffer,0,buffer.Lenght);
                Array.Resize(ref buffer, 1024);
                
                // Receive data from server
                // receive still HELLO message
                buffer = new byte[1024];
                await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                serverResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine("Server: " + serverResponse);
                
                networkStream.Close();
                client.Close();
                return "ok";
            }

        }
        catch(SocketException)
        {
           client.Close();
           return "error";
        }
        finally 
        {
            client.Close();
            return "";
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Please show actual code. Your outline suggests a synchronous workflow, so why are you using async? In async you typically wait for completion before issuing a new call - that is, you issue a new call from the completion callback.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to `await` the asynchronous operations, so you call `ReadAsync` probably even before `WriteAsync` had a chance to start. You're probably code analyzer warnings for unawaited asynchronous operations too. Post the *actual* code

Comment: I've added a part of the real code becouse I can't share the complete one.

Comment: Data is receive in chunks of Max Size of 1500 bytes.  Longer messages are received in multiple chunks and you cannot close connection until all the chunks are received.

Comment: @jdweng @ Panagiotis Kanavos yes but in my case the server sends one response per request and usualy is less than 1500 bytes.

Comment: Does not matter.  Routers and Servers are allowed to break and combine chunk any time during routing.  Windows uses timers to move data up/down the execution chain (from Ethernet adapter to application) and also break messages into chunk using timers.  So you  cannot expect the receive data to come in one chunk.

Comment: @jdweng yes but in my case the server sends one response per request and usually is less than 1500 bytes per response.
 sending the request and receiving the response is not a problem the problem is to receive the data from the second response.I can achieve that only if I put a fixed timeout between the write and read.My goal is to read the data from the second response when they are available and not waiting for fixed amount of time.

Comment: You have to pay attention to the return value from `Read`/`ReadAsync`. They tell you *how many bytes* have been received. There is no guarantee that that corresponds, in any way, with how many bytes were provided to any given call to `Write`/`WriteAsync`. TCP doesn't do *messages*, just an endless stream of bytes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So I have to stay with my timeout solution or compare bytes that i've received until they change. Is that right?

Comment: No, you need to know how big each response is (somehow) and then make sure that you're reading the response *in full* each time. The reason you're seeing (part of) the previous response is because you're not currently doing that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks I will try that.